# CUDA samples run but no nvcc found - Mint 15 64 bit

Tags: c, nvidia, linux-mint

I have downloaded and ran the CUDA 5.0 installer on my Mint 15 64bit distro. After hours of agony adjusting / removing / installing packages, it was able to finish installation - at least that what it said.

I can go run the CUDA samples so I thought hey it's working. However, I just made a new cu file and wanted to compile but it said "nvcc command not found"

I have looked at a topic similar to this here and they are talking about /opt/bin/ directory however on mine, there is no such directory. Does that mean it actually did not install ? It tells me to install nvidia cuda toolkit with apt-get but I am not sure if I should do that.

Also, I did say I ran the CUDA samples fine but I have to say `ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64`

before I can get it to working. Is there a way to automate that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the bin directory of the nvcc compiler driver to your `PATH` (environment variable), and you need to add the appropriate lib directories to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

For an immediate test, this should be as simple as:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib
```

These instructions should be presented to you at the completion of a successful cuda toolkit install, but it seems your install method may have been roundabout.

To make this "automatic" you may want to investigate one of the methods to add these statements to a script run at login.  For example, if you have a `.bashrc` file in your user's home directory, try editing that with the above commands.  It should [probably be sufficient](http://johansja.tumblr.com/post/765167907/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path-in-linux-mint#) to put the above commands at the very end of your `~/.bashrc` file if you have one.

Note that Linux Mint is not one of the [officially supported CUDA distros](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#linux), so your mileage may vary.